# How to run a regression on different variable categories in R?

Tags: r, data-analysis

I need some help with regression in R, when I have categorical data.

#### Example

```
number = c(2, 3, 5, 8, 1, 5, 7, 10, 4, 6) 
quality = c("Poor", "Good", "Very Good", "Perfect", "Good", "Good", "Perfect", "Very Good", "Good", "Poor") 
df = data.frame(number, quality)
x <- lm(number ~ quality)
summary(x)
```

I need to assign somehow different types of categories (Poor, Good, etc.) to different variables, so I can run a regression on individual categories, something like `x <- lm(number ~ poor + good + very good + perfect)`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a reshaping data problem. Try this:

```
number = c(2, 3, 5, 8, 1, 5, 7, 10, 4, 6) 
quality = c("Poor", "Good", "Very Good", "Perfect", "Good", "Good", "Perfect", "Very Good", "Good", "Poor") 
df = data.frame(number, quality)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% mutate(value = 1) %>% spread(quality,value,fill=0)

#   number Good Perfect Poor Very Good
# 1      1    1       0    0         0
# 2      2    0       0    1         0
# 3      3    1       0    0         0
# 4      4    1       0    0         0
# 5      5    1       0    0         1
# 6      6    0       0    1         0
# 7      7    0       1    0         0
# 8      8    0       1    0         0
# 9     10    0       0    0         1
```

You can save this as your new dataset and apply the model you want to any of the new variables.
Also, there are other ways for reshaping data. Try `reshape2` package if you prefer an alternative, or check the `model.matrix` approach that @bunk suggests in the comments below.

Comment: this is the same as fitting a linear model the way the OP did, only without an intercept, consider `model.matrix(number ~ quality-1, data=df[order(df$number),])`, fit by `lm(number ~ quality-1, data=df)`

Comment: You can do that as well, but this reshaped dataset is the only way to get the values of the initial variable `quality` and create new variables (one variable for each value). Then you can do `lm(number ~ Poor + Good + Very Good + Perfect, NewDataset)`. If I'm missing something I'm happy to change or delete my answer.

Comment: Did you manage to run that without a problem? :-) Be careful of the space in the new variable `Very Good`. R doesn't like spaces so you have to add ` before and after the name.

Comment: @AntoniosK I only meant to add a possibly useful way to expand factors in a similar fashion.  The two models are obviously different the way you fit it, so what I said about things being the same etc, was bogus ;).  You could do `cbind.data.frame(df$number, model.matrix(number ~ quality-1, data=df))`, but the names are ugly.

Comment: @bunk Still agree with you on this. I wouldn't say that the column names are ugly us they still make sense. They will be very useful like that if you have 2 variables you need to reshape. Imagine having also another variable that has `Good` as value. Then you end up with two columns named as `Good`. With your method you'll have the initial variable name in front of `Good`. Also, for this example I'd prefer `data.frame(number=df$number, model.matrix(number ~ quality-1, data=df))`. Makes 1st column better and last column without a space.

Comment: you make good points, as things get more complicated or if you want interaction effects, etc., you wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Yes @bunk ! Interactions is another thing you can do easier by using `model.matrix`. By the way, very efficient (time and memory) if you use `sparse.model.matrix` when appropriate (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/sparse.model.matrix.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try google it first!

```
df$quality <- factor(df$quality)
x <- lm(data = df, number ~ quality)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, it produces the same result as my example above. What I want is to run a regression, for example, just number ~ poor (so basically, i want to split poor, good, very good, and perfect into different things and then add the ones that I need).